# Emacs garbled screen on SLURM interactive node

Tags: emacs, slurm, terminfo

When I remotely login a SLURM interactive node, emacs will sometimes garble the screen. As I describe below, I think the issue is that the SLURM interactive node is messing up the Enquiry/acknowledgment terminal signals and some characters are getting dropped causing glitches.

**Setup**

- Computer that I actually interact with: MacBook Air (10.13.2)
- Terminal: iTerm2 Build 3.1.7
- ssh to cluster
- SLURM interactive node (i.e. `srun --nodes=1 ... --pty /bin/bash`)
- emacs: GNU Emacs 27.1  used in terminal mode (i.e. `emacs -nw`)

Sometimes when the screen re-draws, it gets garbled:
[image: Garbled emacs screen]

It seems to happen more when the there are many panes or moving around lots of text.
Based on this part of the emacs [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Screen-Garbled.html), I tried using `C-l (recenter-top-bottom)` to re-draw the screen, and that temporarily fixes the current glitch.

By setting `$TERM=screen` or `$TERM=xterm-256color` in my `.bash-profile` I see different color schemes, but the glitches persist.

Note, I am only seeing the glitches when I login to the interactive node, not from the head node on the cluster. Using the fact that it is ok on the loging node, this can provide useful diagnostic information. This makes me suspect that the issue is that the ENQ/ACK or pad-timing for so characters sent from the cluster are getting dropped. This is discussed in the [documentation](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/tack/tack.html) for the `tack` terminfo diagnostics program.

Using `tack` from both the **login node** and the **interactive node** give the same values

```
$ tack
Using terminfo from: /home/maom/opt/miniconda3/share/terminfo/x/xterm-256color

Name: xterm-256color|xterm with 256 colors
\r ^M (cr)    = ^M
\n ^J (ind)   = ^J
\b ^H (cub1)  = ^H
\t ^I (ht)    = ^I
      (clear) = ^[[H^[[2J
      (home)  = ^[[H
ENQ   (u9)    = ^[[c
ACK   (u8)    = ^[[?1;2c

Terminal size: 204 x 52.  Baud rate: 38400.  Frame size: 10.0
```

Using the `Baudrate test` on the **login node**:

```
1600949 characters per second.  Baudrate 52  Done
```

Using the `Baudrate test` on the **interactive node** the characters per second is about 30% slower:

```
1090426 characters per second.  Baudrate 52  Done
```

And, using the `test ENQ/ACK handshake` on the **login node** gives:

```
Testing ENQ/ACK, standby...
This program expects the ENQ sequence to be answered with the ACK character.  This will help the program reestablish synchronization when the terminal is overrun with data.

ENQ sequence from (u9): ^[[c
ACK received: ^[[?1;2c
Length of ACK 7.  Expected length of ACK 7.
Terminating character found in (u8): c
```

while using the `test ENQ/ACK handshake` on the **interactive node** node gives:

```
Testing ENQ/ACK, standby...

ACK terminating character: c
```

Is there someway I can update the terminfo to fix the glitches work with the cluster admin support to work around the issue?

Comment: probably not - baudrate's relevant if the terminal/connection doesn't have flow control (you'd see that nowadays only if you've connected something to a serial port).

Comment: @ThomasDickey, can you please clarify? Are you saying that this is an issue that can be fixed? or that the this is probably not the issue because this isn't a connection over something that doesn't have flow control a e.g. a serial port?

Comment: The latter - I suspect you're just running into network delays (not much to be done...).

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same problem, and I don't know the best solution, but this could help. First, when you do `srun` it is better to pass `-li` on bash:

```
srun --nodes=1 ... --pty /bin/bash -li
```

This will make sure it loads the interactive bash profile you will usually open when you normally login.

This does not fix the issue completely for me, but but if I do `tmux` in the interactive session and then run `emacs`, then I don't have garbling problem.